# How to make an element not reduce in width in relation to the webpage

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "poppins";
}
body{
    background-color: rgb(214, 255, 255);
}
.article:nth-child(3){
    background-color: white;
}
.article:nth-child(5){
    background-color: white;

}
.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: fit-content;
}
.article:nth-child(1){
    color: white;
    background-color: purple;
}
.article:nth-child(2){
    background-color: #222;
    color: white;
}
.article:nth-child(4){
    background-color: rgb(0, 2, 37);
    color: white;
}
.article{
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 45%;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="article">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque provident quia quidem fuga natus modi? Similique eum est nemo iure eaque debitis veritatis maiores aliquam porro sequi, harum unde quos?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque provident quia quidem fuga natus modi? Similique eum est nemo iure eaque debitis veritatis maiores aliquam porro sequi, harum unde quos?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque provident quia quidem fuga natus modi? Similique eum est nemo iure eaque debitis veritatis maiores aliquam porro sequi, harum unde quos?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque provident quia quidem fuga natus modi? Similique eum est nemo iure eaque debitis veritatis maiores aliquam porro sequi, harum unde quos?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque provident quia quidem fuga natus modi? Similique eum est nemo iure eaque debitis veritatis maiores aliquam porro sequi, harum unde quos?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So as you can see, I'm trying to make these divs align in the center of the webpage without the use flex or grid and not reduce in width in relation to when its viewed in different screen size and also without media queries, In other how to make this elements centerly aligned on the webpage and be as responsive as possible without the property mentioned

Comment: If you don’t want the width to change, what width do you want it to be?

Comment: As long as the element size dosen't reduce as the webpge size is reduced and it's responsive

Comment: How can it be both responsive and maintain the same size?

Comment: It's not going to maintain the same size, but the element shrinks immediately i alter the webpage size, Before the webpage gets to the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
  background: red;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
} 
enter code here
```

This will center the element Horizontally and vertically.

Comment: I understand but its still in relation to the webpage, it reduces width immediately the webpage's size is altered, And i have to apply position relative to the body

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand , you don't even want to use media queries, flex or grid. So, I have a solution, maybe this will help you in anyway.
add this CSS code for container

```css
.container {
  width:100vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items:center;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

and this for article

```css
.article{
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

From what you are asking without using media queries, flex or grid , I don't think that is perfectly achievable , still I think it can work the way you want.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Please do give a thumbs up. Thankyou.